# How to use SQL cmdlets in powershell v1.0?

Tags: sql, powershell

I would like to use SQL INSERT/DELETE/... by Powershell v1.0 cmdlets. My machines cannot be upgraded to powershell v2.0.

Therefore, is there a method to install sqlps on Powershell v1.0 ? OR what cmdlets can i use to manipulate SQL data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in cmdlet for querying SQL in Powershell V2 or V3. There is a cmdlet called invoke-sqlcmd included with SQL Server 2008 and higher. To use invoke-sqlcmd you would need to install SQL Server Management Studio, however if you just want to execute queries you can easily create your own Powershell function. Here's one I call invoke-sqlcmd2:
http://poshcode.org/3448